How to generate and scan qr based on https request - Angular 9
I'm using Angular 9. I try to explain what I want to do and I don't have no idea what to do. So I need QR and when client scan by phone this QR it should be call a https request. This request return url and client should be moved in their phone to this url. I tried to use angularx-qrcode. In HTML I have :
      <div>
        <qrcode qrdata="qrUrl"></qrcode>
      </div>

in typescript I defined qrUrl as
qrUrl: string = `${window.location.origin}/api/MobileApp/GetApp/1`; 

Unfortunatelly it doesn't work. Do you have any idea how to achieve my goal.
I tried:
      <div>
        <qrcode qrdata="qrUrl"></qrcode>
      </div>

in typescript I defined qrUrl as
qrUrl: string = `${window.location.origin}/api/MobileApp/GetApp/1`; 

My solution doesn't work because when I scan this QR I see on my phone: search locallhost and it doesn't call my https request. It just try to search string on google.
